# webview doesnt work ajax jquery on jelly bean

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, webview

My android web app doesnt work on click jquery ajax. I don't know what code should i post because .. okay let me tell what i did try. This is link to my web (forum in malays) http://debatremaja.com/mb/cadang_tajuk . and this is app in google play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.debatremaja&hl=en .

Problem 
+ Thumbs up sign in web link above will run

```
    $(".vote_active").click(function(){
    var topic_id = $(this).data("topic-id");
    var linkto= linktodbcontroller+"insert_vote_by_id_n/"+topic_id;
    //window.location.href = linkto;
    $(this).next(".sum").load(linkto);
    // simple prevent 2nd clicked
    $(this).removeClass("clickable");
    $(this).css("color","#0c0");
    $(this).off("click");
    });
```

- And that working fine on

  - pc web browser , firefox and chrome tested
  - on mobile browser ( android 4.2.2 cyanogemod firefox)
  - my app (link above) on android 2.3 emulator
- Maybe ajax not working in webview ?

  - so i did change android code to

  loadUrl("w3school jquery demo")  // Sorry, i cannot post more than 2 links

  But the button in w3school works fine.
- Other avascript works fine. I did set setJavascriptEnable(True) in web app.
- Problem only happend on my app webview.

Thanks in advance because i had experiance get my question answered less an hour after posting. Great comunity in stackoverflow.

**Edit**
I use google hosted jquery link. is this the problem? I also use try jquery hosted in same domain (debatremaja.com) but same as before. Doesnt work.

- it also doesnt work on cyanogenmod jellybean default Browser (not chrome)

Comment: here is link to w3school mention above [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load)

Comment: Does any JavaScript run? I say this because you must explicitly tell the WebView to enable JavaScript.

Comment: javascript runs ok. [link]http://debatremaja.com/mb/debat/10[/link] in this page, there is button (bbcode) that wil popup window.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, add this line:

```
webview.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);

class JsObject {
    public String toString() { return "injectedObject"; }
}
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new JsObject(), "injectedObject");
webview.loadUrl(url_webview);
```

It's in the [google's doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: thank you. i will try later and commenting again if it works.

Comment: There is no `setPluginsEnabled` method in SDK.

Comment: Plugins are not longer supported. They were deprecated from the API 18